# The simplest way to check if host is online (listening on a port) in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

What's the simplest way to check if anything is listening on net.tcp://localhost:8801/
Preferably using WCF

Answer (score 4):

I don't think WCF is the best way to do that. Simply open a `Socket` (or `TcpClient`) and try connecting to that endpoint.